# VSCode: How to make Beautify and Emmet run on .tpl files (Smarty)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, smarty, emmet, js-beautify

I'm working on an old project on VSCode, and I found out that the html formatter and emmet syntax isn't working for .tpl (Smarty templating engine) files.

It's inconveniencing my workflow, and unfortunately I don't see any extensions in the marketplace for exactly this. I am quite happy to find out how to make extensions (specifically Beautify and Emmet) run on other weird file formats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add this on your `settings.json`.

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "smarty": "html"
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"beautify.language": {
    "html": [
        "smarty"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Add to use .tpl instead of "smarty" and then works fine

Answer (score 1):

In your `settings.json`, add for emmet :

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "smarty": "html"
},
```